# Bash - starting and killing processes

Tags: bash, execution

I need some advice on a "simple" bash script.

I want to start around 500 instances of a program "myprog", and kill all of them after x number of seconds

In short, I have a loop that starts the program in background, and after `sleep x` (number of seconds) `pkill` is called with the program name.

My questions are:

1. How can I verify that after 10 seconds all 500 instances are running? ps and grep combination with counting or is there another way?
2. How can I get a count of how many processes did the pkill (or similar kill functions) actually kill (so that there are not any processes that terminate before the actual timelimit)?
3. How can one redirect the output of pkill(or similar kill functions) so that it doesn't output the killed process information, so that 500 lines of `./initializeTest: line 250:  7566 Terminated ./$myprog` can be avoided. Redirecting to /dev/null didn't do the trick.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2. Use `pgrep`. I don't remember off the top of my head whether `pgrep` has `-c` parameter, so you might need to pipe that to `wc -l`.

3: that output is produced by your shell's job control. I think if you run that as a script (not in an interactive shell), there shouldn't be such an output. For an interactive shell, the are number of ways to turn that off, but they are shell-dependent, so refer to your shell's manual.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip. pgrep does have the -c flag and gives the same result as ps | grep combo. Will use it from now on to make things more readable.

Comment: @Milan: not only that is more readable, but it's actually more reliable. (E.g. `ps | grep combo` may match the `grep` itself, because `combo` is in its command line.)

Comment: That is very true. I always use the grep [x]xxx when I'm counting instances but when tired one can miss that. The output was indeed produced by my shell's job control. That explained why my "redirection" failed. Thanks for very useful information.

Answer (score 2):

In bash there is the `ulimit` command that controls the resources of a (sub)shell.

This, for example, is *guaranteed* to use at most **10 seconds of cpu time** and then die:

```
(ulimit -t 10; ./do_something)
```

That doesn't answer your question but hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: Guaranteed? Can I get a refund? `time (ulimit -t 3; sleep 7)` output: 7.

Comment: @Dennis: but that didn't use much cpu time did it? :)

Comment: But the OP is asking about real time.

Comment: @Dennis: (a) I know, that's why I say "That doesn't answer your question", (b) chances are that OP's processes do much more than `sleep` and (c) there are many other options of `ulimit` that may be of use here.

Answer (score 1):

Well my 2 cents :

1. ps and grep can do the job. I found that kill -0 $pid is better, by the way :) (it tells you if a process is running or not)
2. You can use ps/grep or kill -0. For your problem, I will start all processes in the background and get their pid with `$!`, store them in an array or a list, then use `kill -0` to get the status of all the processes.
3. use `&>` or `2>&1` as it is probably written on stderr

my2c

Comment: Thanks for a fast response. When i tried redirecting, I used &> in order to redirect all output which didnt work. Redirecting to stdout and then to /dev/null didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that each process gets their fair share of 10 seconds before they are killed, I would wrap each command within a subshell with it's own `sleep && kill`.

```
function run_with_tmout {
    CMD=$1; TMOUT=$2
    $CMD & 
    PID=$!
    sleep $TMOUT
    kill $PID 
}

for ((i=0; i < 500; i++)); do 
    run_with_tmout ./myprog 10 &
done

# wait for all child processes to end
wait  && echo "all done"
```

For a more complete example, see [this example from bashcookbook.com](http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3) which first checks if the process is still running, then tries `kill -s SIGTERM` before resorting to `SIGKILL`.

Comment: If `kill -0` fails, that means there's no process at that PID. It doesn't try to kill the process; it just checks for existence. You should do SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGINT, SIGHUP [before you do SIGKILL](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter).

Comment: Thanks dennis, I misquoted the example. Fixing answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using something like the following to get a list of pids.

```
PS=$(ps ax | sed s/^' '*// | grep java | grep program_name | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Then I use `kill $PS` to stop them.

```
!/bin/bash
PS=$(ps ax | sed s/^' '*// | grep java | grep program_name | cut -d' ' -f1)
kill $PS
```